# Clion SFML Убрать предупреждение неинициализирован sf::event

Tags: c++, clion, sfml, warning

Clion просит чтобы я инициализировал sf::Event event. Как это сделать?
[Код](https://pastebin.com/DyBrMtZP)

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sf::Event event{};
После этого clion перестал ругатся.

Comment: The check also flags variables with automatic storage duration that have record types without a user-provided constructor and are not initialized. The suggested fix is to zero initialize the variable via {} for C++11 and beyond or = {} for older language versions. [Источник](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init.html)

Comment: Вы можете дополнить ответ кнопкой "править" и дать тем самым исчерпывающий ответ на собственный вопрос. Это может сделать топик полезным для других и поднять вам репутацию.